# Probability of the next number in a random sequence being the largest seen so far

Tags: probability

Suppose I have a uniform random number generator producing a sequence of random numbers in the range $0...100$. I am trying to work out what the probability is that the $n^{th}$ number in this sequence is the greatest of any numbers seen so far.

My initial thoughts were that the probability of the first number being the greatest so far is obviously $1$. Since the expected value for any generated number is $50$, the probability of the second number being greater than this would be $0.5$. I could not see a way to apply this logic to the third number, but after performing a simple trial, it doesn't look like the answer is $1/2^n$, in fact, it looks more like the answer is simply $1/n$.

Can anybody explain this?

---

I also thought of two extensions to this question:

1. What is the expected value for the number of times that the newly generated value was the largest seen so far in a sequence of length $n$? This part is in fact the real point of interest. For example, in the sequence **28**, 26, **60**, **93**, 67, 71, 16, 49, **94**, 91, the number of times a new value was the greatest is 4.
2. How would all this be affected by a non-uniformly distributed number generator, for example if the numbers were normally distributed about $50$, with some defined variance?

Comment: One of the numbers has to be the largest...as they are all independent, the probability that any given one is the largest is $\frac 1n$.

Comment: Wow thanks @lulu, that's actually pretty embarrassingly simple

Comment: @lulu: if you are sampling without replacement from the integers $0,\ldots 100$ then they are not independent but the probability is still $\frac1n$ for $n \le 101$.  Perhaps  symmetry is as good an argument.

Comment: @Henry  You are correct, I should have appealed to symmetry without evoking a (nonexistent) independence.  In truth, I didn't notice the "without replacement" clause...as you say, that doesn't change the symmetry.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming no ties, the order statistics for the first $n$ numbers can take $n!$ equally probable patterns.  $(n-1)!$ of these have the last as the largest number.

So the probability the $n$th number seen is the largest of the first $n$ is $\dfrac{(n-1)!}{n!}=\dfrac1n$

Comment: Thanks @Henry, do you have any thoughts on the extra parts of the question?

Comment: @scary_jeff:  Assuming a continuous uniform distribution on $[0,1]$, the probability that all of the first $n-1$ numbers are less than or equal to $x$ is $x^{n-1}$, so the probability the $n$th is the greatest so far is $\int_0^1 (1-x^{n-1})\,dx = \left[x-\frac1n x^n\right]_0^1 = \frac1n$.  The expected value of the largest of the first $n-1$ is  $\int_0^1 (n-1) x^{n-1}\,dx = \frac{n-1}{n}$ which means that after $2$ numbers the expected value of the larger is $\frac23$ not the $\frac34$ you thought.

Comment: surely the number of times that a value was the largest so far in a sequence of length $n$ must be at least 1? From what I can see, it relates to $ln(n)$, but again I don't know why.

Comment: @scary_jeff: [Harmonic series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_series_(mathematics)) $\sum \frac1n$

Comment: @Henry shouldn't the probability be $\int_0^1 x^{n-1}dx = 1/n$ ?

Comment: @apt45: your $\frac 1n$ is the same as mine, so I do not understand your question. There may be more than one way to answer the question

Comment: @Henry I am referring to your comment. the integrand is different. Your equation returns $1-\frac{1}{n}$ instead of $\frac{1}{n} $

Comment: So you were commenting on my old comment - you may be right

Answer (score 2):

The average number of times is:
The first number every time;
the second number half the time;
the third number one-third the time...
So the average number is 
$$1+\frac12+\frac13+\frac14+\cdots+\frac1n$$
This is roughly equal to $$\ln(n)+0.577$$
and $0.57721..$ is the 'Euler-Mascheroni constant'

This is the same for any distribution, so long as you don't have ties.
Also, if every number is chosen from the set $\{1,2,3\}$, you run out of 'highest so far' quite quickly.

Comment: Thanks @Micheal, but how did you arrive at this result?

Comment: Lulu explained why the third number is the highest a third of the time.  The sum is well-known, it comes up in calculus courses, and is because the integral of $1/x$ is $\ln x$